How do I move the search bar and the login to the circled areas (blue is login, red is search)? This is HTML and CSS

This is for a Web Design Assessment that I've been working on almost everyday for the past 17 weeks and haven't gotten very far. While there are plenty of other things I still need to do (and with only a week left to do it.) this one problem has plagued me the whole time. I just can't seem to get things to align properly. I wish to have the search bar, wishlist and shopping cart (all together) lined up neatly next to the login, however it doesn't matter how I change it, it doesn't move even slightly. Image above is approximately where I want things to go.


/* Reset some default browser styles */

body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header styles */

header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.featured {
  display: flex;
}


/* Sets location of product images on pages */

.product1 {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product2 {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product3 {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 150px;
}

.logo-text {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.logo-container {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
}


/* Center the menu items */

.sidenav {
  height: 85%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background: color #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}


/* When hovering over link, it changes colour */

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 800px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidebar (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img src="TipToeSoles_Logo_colour.png" alt="TipToe Soles Logo" class="logo">
      <div class="logo-text">TipToe Soles</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a>
    <!-- Add more menu items as needed -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <div class="featured">
    <div class="product1">
      <img src="Work and Walk Chesnut.jpg" alt="Work and Walk Chesnut">
      <h2>Work and Walk Chesnut</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product2">
      <img src="Gary Tan.jpg" alt="Gary Tan">
      <h2>Gary Tan</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product3">
      <img src="Gary Black.jpg" alt="Gary Black">
      <h2>Gary Black</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>© 2024 TipToe Soles. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</footer>



Also is it possible to make the searchbar, and the login actually work and function?
If anyone can help me find a solution to this, I will be grateful. Thank you in advance.
Switching around the ids, classes and messing with different alignments. For some reason nothing changes.

Why did you omit the code for login and search bar? how your code should help us to figure out the problem? You should create a Minimal, Reproducible Example You should also focus on asking one question at a time, your question contains multiple currently.

"Switching around the ids, classes and messing with different allignments. For some reason nothing changes." If you remove the backtick quotes surrounding your css content you would see changes taking effect.

Also, in your css file, change align-items: left; to align-items: start; and change background: color #111; to background-color: #111;
